# can't run sublime text

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

after I install sublime-text on ubuntu, I have tried 16.04 32 bit and 64 bit, I get many errors when I try to run it with the command prompt subl.

This is how I am installing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

after this I have checked that subl exists in my /usr/bin/ directory

Below is the error I receive when I run subl in the command line, please help, thank you:

> Unable to load libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_cairo_create from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_cursor_new_for_display from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_cursor_unref from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_display_get_default from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_display_get_pointer from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_error_trap_pop from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_error_trap_push from
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gdk_input_add from libgdk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gdk_input_remove from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_keymap_translate_keyboard_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to
>   load gdk_keyval_to_unicode from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_region_get_rectangles from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_default from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_height from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_root_window from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_width from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_n_monitors from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_point from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_screen_get_resolution from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_unicode_to_keyval from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_get_frame_extents from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_get_origin from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_get_state from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_invalidate_rect from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_set_cursor from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_window_move_resize from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_x11_get_server_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gdk_x11_get_xatom_by_name_for_display from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to
>   load gdk_x11_window_set_user_time from libgdk-x11-2.0.so Unable to
>   load libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_accel_group_new from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask
>   from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_box_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_box_pack_start from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label
>   from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_check_menu_item_set_active
>   from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_clear from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_get from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_text from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_set_with_data from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_store from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_clipboard_wait_for_text from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_container_add from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_container_get_children from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_container_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_container_remove from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_dialog_add_button from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_dialog_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_dialog_run from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_dialog_set_default_response from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_drag_dest_set from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_drag_finish from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_add_filter from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_get_filename from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_get_files from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to
>   load gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable
>   to load gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_file_chooser_set_select_multiple
>   from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_file_filter_add_pattern from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_file_filter_new from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_file_filter_set_name from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_get_current_event_time from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_im_context_filter_keypress from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_im_context_set_client_window from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_im_multicontext_new from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_init from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_init_check from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_main from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_main_quit from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_attach_to_widget from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_bar_new from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_label from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_submenu from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_new_with_label from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_label from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_submenu from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_item_set_use_underline from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_menu_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_menu_popup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_menu_shell_append from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_menu_shell_get_type from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_message_dialog_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_message_dialog_new_with_markup from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to
>   load gtk_selection_data_get_uris from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_selection_data_set_text from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_separator_menu_item_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_settings_get_default from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_show_uri from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_vbox_new from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_add_accelerator from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_add_events from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_destroy from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_get_display from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_get_parent from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_get_screen from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_get_window from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_grab_focus from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_hide from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_remove_accelerator from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_set_app_paintable from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_set_colormap from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_set_double_buffered from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_set_sensitive from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_show from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_show_all from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_widget_size_request from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_add_accel_group from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_fullscreen from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_get_type from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_iconify from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_maximize from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_move from
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load gtk_window_new from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_window_present_with_time from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_window_remove_accel_group from libgtk-x11-2.0.so
>   Unable to load gtk_window_resize from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_default_icon_list from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_default_size from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_keep_above from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_modal from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_position from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_title from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_transient_for from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_type_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_stick from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_unfullscreen from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_widget_modify_bg from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_decorated from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so Unable to load
>   gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint from libgtk-x11-2.0.so

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `libgtk` is missing in your ubuntu.

You can try installing the same by:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of all the error messages, but now when I type "subl" into the command line, nothing happens. I am connecting to this machine via an ssh does would this make a difference, if so how to solve this?

Comment: Yes. Sublime is a ui based and cannot be opened via ssh in terminal. Are you using any vnc or nomachine client? Otherwise, you can even try logging by `ssh -X` and then run sublime. If you just want to edit files without using sublime, use `vim` editor.

Comment: ok, when I get home from work today I will try installing vim editor.

Comment: I normally log in like this "ssh root@ipAddressHere" In order to make ssh -X work do I just type "ssh -X root@ipAddressHere" ... I did this and typing the subl command still does nothing. I have nano as a text editor and am happy to use it, unless you think vim is much better, I would just love to be able to get sublime text or something like it to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. Try `-X` option. vim has very tough learning curve. But once you pick up, its very useful in ssh sessions.